# How would the land life look like in an ecosystem based on chemosynthesis?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, environment

So let's imagine a rogue planet. It's far from any sun, and the very little light it receives from the stars is way too low to sustain any form of photosynthesis. Thankfully, this planet also has a lot of volcanic activity. Thanks to its thick atmosphere and aforementioned volcanic activity the surface of the planet is warm, and its oceans are liquid. It is very similar to Earth from geological perspective, just with more volcanic activity.

There are already simple organisms living deep underwater around thermal vents, and in time, they will evolve into more advanced  organisms similar to what we know from Earth's oceans. But that's the ocean, what about the land?

How would the land life look on a world without sun, where the only sources of energy are volcanoes and geysers/hot springs? How would the organisms evolve and adapt to the conditions of this world? Would it even be possible for there to be any advanced land life in such a world?

As I said before, the climate on the surface is warm, with temperatures ranging from 20C to 40C depending on the weather. The geothermal sources of energy are abundant, ranging from large geysers and hot springs to lava lakes and volcanoes, but they are the only source of energy outside the ocean. How would the life adapt to live in such conditions?

Comment: You aren't going to find a warm thick atmosphere or liquid oceans on a rogue planet.

Comment: @rek unless its an underground ocean. the thick atmo though wont be happening unless its an ice giant though, or its a close moon of a rogue gas giant

Comment: @rek ...until they do.

Comment: What land life?

Answer (score 11):

You do have a minor problem.

Oxygen.

Earth-based life forms depend on atmospheric oxygen for energy, something that would be very hard to imagine on your planet. It is for sure the land life would not depend on oxygen.

The fact that aquatic life on earth CAN survive without atmospheric oxygen is now established, but it is based on the ability of the organism to extract [oxygen from water](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2001/ast13apr_1/).

> Deep-sea bacteria form the base of a varied food chain that includes
> shrimp, tubeworms, clams, fish, crabs, and octopi. All of these
> animals must be adapted to endure the extreme environment of the vents
> -- complete darkness; water temperatures ranging from 2°C (in ambient seawater) to about 400°C (at the vent openings); pressures hundreds of
> times that at sea level; and high concentrations of sulfides and other
> noxious chemicals.
>
> The ability of life to tap such geothermal energy raises interesting
> possibilities for other worlds like Jupiter's moon Europa, which
> probably harbors liquid water beneath its icy surface. Europa is
> squeezed and stretched by gravitational forces from Jupiter and the
> other Galilean satellites. Tidal friction heats the interior of Europa
> possibly enough to maintain the solar system's biggest ocean. Could
> similar hydrothermal vents in Europa's dark seas fuel vent ecosystems
> like those found on Earth? The only way to know is to go there and
> check.

So yes, advanced life forms can survive without photosynthesis, but this begs the question be asked "Where and how did these other higher order life forms evolve? Did they evolve around the vents, or did they evolve elsewhere and return to the vents?" Any sea life that depends on the [amoeba in the evolutionary chain](https://carnegiescience.edu/news/amoeba-may-offer-key-clue-photosynthetic-evolution) will depend on photosynthesis.

> Clearly the events that gave rise to chloroplasts and mitochondria
> changed the world forever. But it is difficult to research the process
> by which this happened because it took place so long ago. One strategy
> used to elucidate the way in which this process evolved has relied on
> identifying organisms for which the events that resulted in the
> conversion of a bacterium into a host-dependent organelle occurred
> more recently.
>
> Nowack and Grossman focused their research on a type of amoeba called
> Paulinella chromatophora, which contains two photosynthetic
> compartments that also originated from an endosymbiotic
> cyanobacterium, but that represent an earlier stage in the formation
> of a fully evolved organelle.

The NASA article goes on to say, at the end,

> Editor's note: Michael Meyer, the Astrobiology Discipline Scientist at
> NASA headquarters remarks: "Right now, the hydrothermal systems are
> dependent on oxygen as the electron acceptor, which comes from
> photosynthesis. But it does raise the possibility of a thriving
> hydrothermal system in an anoxic environment, presumably driven by H2S
> going to elemental sulfur (and not sulfate)."

So it seems the author is proposing a life form that can survive on H2S and not H2O. That is, it would not be dependent on oxygen in the atmosphere, but sulphur in the atmosphere, which would be plentiful on your world. And sulphur hexafloride is an excellent [greenhouse gas](https://www.epa.gov/ghgemissions/understanding-global-warming-potentials), able to retain heat much better than CO2.

> Chlorofluorocarbons (CFCs), hydrofluorocarbons (HFCs),
> hydrochlorofluorocarbons (HCFCs), perfluorocarbons (PFCs), and **sulfur
> hexafluoride (SF6)** are sometimes called high-GWP gases because, for a
> given amount of mass, they trap substantially more heat than CO2. (The
> GWPs for these gases can be in the thousands or tens of thousands.) [emphasis mine]

It turns out that sulphur has, indeed, [been proposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_types_of_biochemistry) as an alternative to oxygen as an hypothesis, but not completely proven, except at the bacterial level.

> Sulfur is also able to form long-chain molecules, but suffers from the
> same high-reactivity problems as phosphorus and silanes. The
> biological use of sulfur as an alternative to carbon is purely
> hypothetical, especially because sulfur usually forms only linear
> chains rather than branched ones. (The biological use of sulfur as an
> electron acceptor is widespread and can be traced back 3.5 billion
> years on Earth, thus predating the use of molecular oxygen.[20]
> Sulfur-reducing bacteria can utilize elemental sulfur instead of
> oxygen, reducing sulfur to hydrogen sulfide.)

So yes, it is well within speculation given our current knowledge that a significantly evolved life pyramid could evolve on your planet, based on sulphur and not carbon-oxygen. The heavy concentration of sulphur in the atmosphere would, in fact, explain the relative warmth of the atmosphere and the lack of radiation back into space that would otherwise cool the planet. These creatures could be hypothesized to be air-breathing, very similar to Earth creatures, except that they breathe sulphur and not oxygen.

But can we even pretend to know what their 'blood' and their 'lungs' would look like? Methinks not.

**ADDENDUM EDIT**

There is, in fact, [evidence](https://scienceillustrated.com.au/blog/science/early-life-on-earth-had-sulphur-based-metabolisms/) that a more evolved sulphur-based life form did exist on earth.

> Researchers from the University of Western Australia (UWA) and Oxford
> University have unearthed the best preserved sulphur-based
> microfossils on Earth. The 3.4-billion-year-old fossils consist of
> carbonaceous cells, along with the protective sheaths that housed some
> of these cells.

> The discovery provides strong evidence for early life on Earth
> subsisting on sulphur, rather than oxygen. “These are now the oldest
> well-preserved microfossils on Earth and the discovery bypasses much
> of the controversy that has surrounded previous, more poorly preserved
> microfossils of about the same age,” said postdoctoral research
> fellow the Dr David Wacey from UWA, lead author of the paper published
> in Nature Geoscience.

Comment: But that is TERRESTRIAL biology. There is no real need for it to be oxygen-based, there are enough alternatives. It was just abundant on earth so organisms started to use it

Comment: @Hobbamok    "...  they will evolve into more advanced organisms similar to what we know from Earth's oceans." That pretty much defines it as 'TERRESTRIAL biology'.

Comment: OR, Justin, he means that there will be an evolution from the oceans to the land, similar to what we know happened on Earth.

Comment: @Hobbamok  Equally valid of an interpretation.

Answer (score 6):

A very important component of this ecosystem (which is similar to that which we expect on the far side of most tidally locked habitable planets orbiting red dwarf stars) is the **[anti-solar cell](https://www.ucdavis.edu/news/anti-solar-cells-photovoltaic-cell-works-night)**.  You may have read of Bedouins who, in ancient times before conventional refrigeration, made ice in the Sahara by exposing pans of water to the starlit sky.  Producing ice means extracting usable energy, and the anti-solar cell does it more directly.  Still, I was very *surprised* by the amount of power it is said to be able to produce!

With this level of power generation, we can expect these planetary darksides to be adorned with forests and fields not so different from our own - less efficient, to be sure, and slower growing, but still sustaining interesting ecologies of the night.  We might even suppose that, as bacteriorhodopsins eventually evolved into our photoreceptors, that the animals of these worlds might see by darkness - by their ability to radiate small amounts of heat, via infrared photons, from specific parts of their retinas.  (Retinas in a loose sense - I realize I should take another look at the capabilities of pit vipers.  We always think of them as seeing the heat from prey, but what about seeing the cold of night?)

Comment: The problem is a detail that OP completely overlooks: the planet has to be heavily isolated somehow. Possibly with a thiccccccc athmosphere or even a layer of ice above the "sky" or something like that. Because if the planet is actually radiating enough heat for your anti-solar to work, the whole thing looses way to much heat

Comment: The release of heat was the question's premise.  Looking at distant planets, Pluto isn't toasty warm, but the waters of Neptune are much too hot for life.  Naturally we would expect an Earth in such a position or further to be cold, but what about a super-Earth?  What if it formed near the site of a neutron star merger and had many more radioactive elements, or had a large moon in close orbit?  The premise is unlikely, but not so much so that I would reject the question outright.

Answer (score 3):

### REAL Alternative Energy:

I can't speak of what the biochemistry and final electron acceptors of this world will be, but it could exist in your thermal environment if you have organisms using biological [heat engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine)/[thermoelectric generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator)/[(electro)mechanical](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Muhammad_Hassan_Khan_Niazi2/publication/284347416_Energy_Harvesting_Model_From_Tree_And_Grass_Movement_Using_Piezoelectric_Effect/links/5f9c616292851c14bcf6352d/Energy-Harvesting-Model-From-Tree-And-Grass-Movement-Using-Piezoelectric-Effect.pdf) energy harvesting instead of chemosynthesis. I'm not saying chemosynthesis wouldn't still be big, but it isn't going to be the driver of eukaryotic organisms. Your plants will resemble bio-machines. They may even use electricity (why not?)

Our life evolved to take advantage of the endless sunlight streaming down like manna from heaven, but here that isn't an option. certainly bacteria could evolve, but complex multicellular life might need a little more to justify why they get big. Chemical energy would need a rationale as to why it moved and spread.

For starters, your organisms would need to be bigger to take advantage of temperature differences between one place and another. Intense heat sources (vulcanism) mean that the large gradients of heat would be exploitable by fairly small multicellular organisms, but to take advantage of more subtle differences, pressure to evolve bigger and more complex structures would result in plant-like life that spread across the ground, and eventually spread upwards to make radiator-like "plants" conducting heat from the ground into the air (or vice versa).

Once "plants" are scaling into the skies, why not take advantage of piezoelectric effects and have plants powered by the swaying in the winds of your volcanos, or prevailing winds from planetary rotation? If there is an equivalent to the jet stream on your world (a big if) then organisms would have pressure to grow really tall, then create fans to resist the winds.

Now that you have organisms harvesting energy from the environment, the sky is the limit. The types of plants would depend on things like winds, and if the ground/air was cold or hot. So ecosystems would evolve. Everything your ecology needs is present. Would this harvesting result in biochemical reactions generating oxygen? Life doesn't use biomechanical power harvesting. At that point, you could justify all sorts of things. Organisms could even use electricity directly, storing chemicals to make power, or having mechanical batteries, or (most likely, given chemosynthetic ancestors) acting just like life on Earth, with mundane chemistry reactions powering organisms. The choices are yours.